# Way to change sys.path insert so it reflects where file path is actually located?

Tags: python

I have a Python automation script that is going to be implemented across several team members devices. The problem is, once we get the folder onto each device we have to manually go in and change the ID (since mine is there) to the person's ID.

Example of code that grabs where the file is - where ****** is ID that needs to be changed every time.

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Users/******/Projects (4 fun)/Automation/Help Integration')
```

Is there any way to automatically switch it to the right ID since the folder path placement is going to be the same across all devices?

Comment: Easiest solution would probably be to not f*** with sys.path at all.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the username? os.getlogin()